# Typeahead Bloodhound, showing results as undefined. Wrong JSON type?

Tags: php, jquery, json, typeahead, bloodhound

I am using Typeahead to make an autocomplete search textbox and the dropdown results are showing as undefined.
Apparently the PHP does build the JSON, I have tested it. The problem might be a wrong JSON type.
Here is the PHP:

```
$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

  //Replaces spaces for +
  $searchTerm = preg_replace('/\s/', '+', $row['products_keyword']);

  $a_json_row["search"] = $searchTerm;
  $a_json_row["label"] = $row['products_keyword'];
  array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}

echo json_encode ($a_json); //Return the JSON Array
```

And here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var keywordsVar = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('label'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 'keywords.php?query=%QUERY'

  });

  keywordsVar.initialize();
  $('#idkeywords').typeahead({
    hint: false,
    highlight: true,
    minLenght: 2
  }, {
    name: 'keywords',
    displaykey: 'label',
    source: keywordsVar.ttAdapter()
  });
});
```

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
[{"search":"Artichokes","label":"Artichokes"},
{"search":"Artichokes+2","label":"Artichokes 2"},
{"search":"Artichokes+3","label":"Artichokes 3"}]
```

Can anyone spot the problem??

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: `echo json_encode ($a_json); //Return the JSON Array` - wrong, it returns json of an object. `json_encode ($a_json, true);` returns json of array

Comment: Is not a php error, I guess it has to do with what I am returning (objects, arrays?)

Comment: what is the structure of `a_json`? how does it look like? please add it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in typeahead declaration. It should be `displayKey` with a capitalized k.

Here is a [Reference](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets)

Comment: LOL, that was it. Half a day thrown away! Thanks!